# Correct MySQL Index for this Simple Query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a simple query that does a group by and order by (with a join), but it doesn't seem to be working without temporary tables, and filesort. Here is the query:

```
SELECT items.name, max(activity.created_at), count(items.item_id) as total_count
FROM activity
INNER JOIN items ON activity.item_id = items.item_id 
WHERE activity.user_id = 'XXX'  
GROUP BY activity.item_id 
order by activity.created_at desc
LIMIT 0, 15
```

I have an index on:

```
(activity.item_id, activity.user_id, activity.created_at) - idx_item_created 
(activity.user_id, activity.created_at) - user_id_2
```

When I force idx_item_created it does a full table scan, by default it runs using user_id_2 and always produces:

```
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Anyway to optimize this query better?

Comment: I suggest giving max(activity.created_at) an alias and sorting by that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to have a filesort on this, because you have `group by` and `order by` with two different expressions.  For this query:

```
SELECT items.name, max(activity.created_at), count(items.item_id) as total_count
FROM activity INNER JOIN
     items
     ON activity.item_id = items.item_id 
WHERE activity.user_id = 'XXX'  
GROUP BY activity.item_id 
order by activity.created_at desc
LIMIT 0, 15
```

The best index is a covering index on `activity`:  `activity(user_id, item_id, created_at)`.  This will not eliminate the file sort, though.

Comment: What's the issue with this index? (activity.item_id, activity.user_id, activity.created_at)

Comment: @gregavola . . . `user_id` is not the first key in the index, so it doesn't use the index for filtering.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work - I tried adding the new index - but the the end results is it's using the index - but (still using temporary)